# Set VS Code autoImports action to use ES syntax

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a node project in VS Code with a `package.json` file that has the `"type": "module"` set. when I type in an export name from another file the autoImport functionality automatically writes the import statement for me; although I would like it to write the import statement using ES modules syntax. currently, it imports it using `require` which doesn't make much sense since I wrote the export using ES syntax. how do I get VS Code to behave this way?

// example.js

```js
export default function reader() {}
```

this is how the import works currently
[image: auto-import]

Answer (score 0):

I use this [plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) for auto import. Maybe this plugin will help you too.